# SSRS Force single sided printing

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

The Current the windows pc have the printer settings defaulted to double sided printing to save paper.
There are some reports which they would like SSRS to ignore the windows settings and print single sided.

I dont think this is possible, is it?

Comment: Would printing only on every other page work as a solution? A disadvantage of this is when printed to a non-duplex printer it would insert blank pages.

Answer (score 1):

That setting is specified on a printer driver, and not on a report. So you are correct, it's not possible.

A workaround could be to define two devices for the same printer, one with duplex enabled, the other without.

Comment: Thank you, i know this to be correct but customer is double checking